# Angular websocket moving the methods into a service

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, rxjs

I can a component with some code that does 2 things...

1. Connects to the server via websocket
2. Sends a message and displays the reply.

This works fine and here is the code for the component:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject';

export class Message {
  constructor(
      public sender: string,
      public content: string,
      public isBroadcast = false,
  ) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-terminal',
  templateUrl: './terminal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./terminal.component.scss']
})
export class TerminalComponent {

  public serverMessages = new Array<Message>();
  public clientMessage = '';
  public isBroadcast = false;
  public sender = 'client';

  private socket$: WebSocketSubject<Message>;

  server1 = 'ws://localhost:8999';

  constructor() {}

  public send() {
      const message = new Message(this.sender, this.clientMessage, this.isBroadcast);
      this.serverMessages.push(message);
      this.socket$.next(message);
      this.clientMessage = '';
  }

  connectToServer(serverUrl) {

      this.serverMessages = [];
      this.clientMessage = '';

      this.socket$ = new WebSocketSubject(serverUrl);

      this.socket$.subscribe(
          (message) => this.serverMessages.push(message),
          (err) => console.error(err),
          () => console.warn('Completed!')
      );

  }

}
```

Both methods: connectToServer() and send() work fine.

But I want to add the methods to a service so I can then reuse it on other components and not have to use all the code again.

So I've created the service:

Here is where I am:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject';

export class Message {
  constructor(
      public sender: string,
      public content: string,
      public isBroadcast = false,
  ) { }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService {

  public serverMessages = new Array<Message>();
  public clientMessage = '';
  public isBroadcast = false;
  public sender = 'client';

  private socket$: WebSocketSubject<Message>;

  server1 = 'ws://localhost:8999';

  constructor() {}

  connect(serverUrl) {

   // Do Something

  }

  send(message) {

    // Do something

  }

}
```

My question is...how do I go about the methods in the service so I can just call it from the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular servives are provided to the components using [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).

In your case you already have an injectable service, so as next step it should be added in a `module` in the `providers` section. (Most probably in `app.module.ts`.):

```
...
providers: [
 ...
 WebsocketService,
 ...
],
...
```

After that you are able to inject the service in the components in the constructor following way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-terminal',
  templateUrl: './terminal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./terminal.component.scss']
})
export class TerminalComponent {

  constructor(private websocketService: WebsocketService) {}

}
```

In the above example, I added the `private` modifier in the constructor for `websocketService`. This means that `websocketService` will be available as global private variable in the `TerminalComponent` class. It follows that you can call your functions in the service following way:

```
this.websocketService.connect(serverUrl)
this.websocketService.send(message)
```

However there could be a problem with this solution. The `WebsocketService` is provided by the `root` injector. This means that the service will be a singleton for all components. It follows, when you call the `connect` function from a component and you call the `connect` function from another component you will overwrite the instance of `this.socket$` variable in the service.

Comment: If you will have one service in the root scope than yes, you are right. It can not be just a copy and pasted, because in this case you will face the problem I raised at the end of this post.  

However, if you inject the service to each component "sandboxed" than actually it should work with a copy-paste as well because each of your components will have its own WebsocketService. You can find an example about "sandboxing" here:
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#multiple-service-instances-sandboxing

Comment: Is `this.socket$.next(message);` called somewhere? Is the `subscribe` to the `socket$` in your code also commented?